# What's the relationship between OWL, RDFs, RDFa, Dublin Core and FOAF?

Tags: xml, xsd, rdf, owl, semantic-web

Semantic web can be described as Layer Structure. 
we have URI in the button layer which is the unique identifier for data.
and then we hay syntax like : xml, ns and xml xmls
next it is the way how can we interpret semantic data : RDF
and above RDF, we have RDFs, and OWL is independent from RDFs? but OWL, Dublin Core and FOAF is kind of RDFa? what's the structure between those ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dublin Core and FOAF are schemas, i.e. vocabularies you can use to mark up your data.

OWL (and RDFS) are languages for writing new schemas / vocabularies / ontologies. OWL and RDFS schemas are written using RDF.

RDFa is a syntax for writing RDF (other examples are RDF/XML and Turtle).

Yes, this is all quite confusing!